# Esri ST_Geometry function to make line from points

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

I'm attempting to write a SQL statement that joins two point feature classes, both in an Oracle ArcSDE geodatabase using `ST_Geometry`, and selects a line geometry connecting the points of each resulting row. In PostGIS I would use the function `ST_MakeLine(pt1, pt2)`, but I haven't been able to find this in the Esri docs. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Nearly all your options run through Well-Known Text, so formatting the string to include pt1.ST_X(),p1.ST_Y, pt2.ST_X(), pt2.ST_Y() with a comma inside double-parens is your fastest route.